# Create XSL from XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to dynamically generate an XSLT document from an XSLT stylesheet. In principle this works, of course, but I do not get the namespaces working. I want to have the generated XSLT elements to be prefixed with "xsl" prefix:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...>
```

rather than

```
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

I played around with namespace="" of xsl:element and with xsl:namespace but I do not get it working (xslt2/saxon available)

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use XSLT to create XSLT code then using http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-namespace-alias helps e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  xmlns:axsl="file://namespace.alias">

<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <axsl:stylesheet version="2.0">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </axsl:stylesheet>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="elements">
  <axsl:template match="/">
     <axsl:comment select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>
     <axsl:apply-templates/>
  </axsl:template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="block">
  <axsl:template match="{.}">
     <fo:block><axsl:apply-templates/></fo:block>
  </axsl:template>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, this is the solution! But as I found out, it is also possible to use "xsd" itself (see my solution). Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: In your comment you say 'to use "xsd" itself', I guess you mean `xsl` there instead of `xsd`. As for your post with doing `<xsl:element name="xsl:stylesheet">`, if you want to use that way you can do that, but I prefer to write literal result elements and attributes as long as I don't need to compute a node name dynamically and that way using a namespace alias allows me to continue to write literal result elements and attributes instead of the more cumbersome and wordy `xsl:element` and/or `xsl:attribute`. So for brevity and elegance I would strongly suggest to use a namespace alias.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
<xsl:element name="xsl:stylesheet">
</xsl:element>
```

does the job! (i.e., avoid using namespace="" but explicitely list the namespace prefix)

Comment: If you really want to learn something -- which is the main purpose of SO -- then follow the easier and standard XSLT way of generating a stylesheet -- as recommended both in my answer and that of Martin Honnen.

Comment: Good workaround for XSLT Processors which do not support xsl:namespace-alias, such as Transformiix

Answer (score 1):

The [`xsl:namespace-alias`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-namespace-alias) instruction was designed having exactly this use case in mind -- just start using it in your work.

Here is a real-world example:

http://dnovatchev.wordpress.com/2006/10/21/a-stylesheet-to-write-xslt-code/